# Replacing value in string depending on inner value

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to make a template string that has place holders which are replaced by values from a database depending on their inner value. 
ie, the template would look like this:

> ```
> No: {Job_Number}
> Customer: {Cust_Name}
> Action: {Action}
> ```

The template could be changed to anything, with any column value being inside the brackets.. 
I can not figure a elegant way to get the inner values and replace them with the values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been my solution for this.

Give your format string you can do something like this :

```
// this is a MatchEvaluater for a regex replace
string me_setFormatValue(Match m){
    // this is the key for the value you want to pull from the database
    // Job_Number, etc...
    string key = m.Groups[1].Value;

    return SomeFunctionToGetValueFromKey(key);
}


void testMethod(){
    string format_string = @"No: {Job_Number}
Customer: {Cust_Name}
Action: {Action}";

    string formatted = Regex.Replace(@"\{([a-zA-Z_-]+?)\}", format_string, me_SetFormatValue);
}
```

Comment: It works, but its a shame to use regex for such thing, efficiency-wise.

Comment: I think the performance hit will be negligible, unless he has this in a critical loop.

Comment: I like the theory.. but the regex doesnt work as \{ is an unregoised escape symbol.

Comment: @michael see edit--I don't have access to visual studio at home so I'm writing blind.  You need to put `@` in front of the string

Comment: still doesnt work. but it doesnt matter, its time i brush up on my RegExp anyway. I keep learning it.. and forgetting it.

Comment: fair enough--I'm not even sure if you need to escape the `{` and `}` in this context.  If you remember, let me know what you do so i can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a struct or a class to represent it, and override the ToString.
You probably already have a class the is logically what you are formatting into a string.

```
public class StringHolder
{
    public int No;
    public string CustomerName;
    public string Action;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("No: {1}{0}Customer: {2}{0}Action: {3}",
                             Environment.NewLine,
                             this.No,
                             this.CustomerName,
                             this.Action);
    }
}
```

Then you simply change the properties, and put the instance.ToString in it's destination again for the value to update.

You can make the StringHolder class more general like so:

```
public class StringHolder
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, string> Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ToString(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public string ToString(string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, this.Values.Select(kvp => string.Format("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return this.Values[key]; }
        set { this.Values[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

And then usage would be:

```
var sh = new StringHolder();

sh["No"] = jobNum;
sh["Customer"] = custName;
sh["Action"] = action;

var s = sh.ToString();
```